# How to mark a checkbox with a button

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have the following scenario. I have created a button in the grid detail. At the time of selecting a record and clicking on the button, the checkbox is marked but I cannot get it to register in the database.

I have attached the DAC and Graph

You can help me with this, which comments are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

```
namespace PX.Objects.PM
{
    public class PMBudgetExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.PM.PMBudget>
    {
        #region UsrVendorID


        [PXDBInt]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Vendor ID", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
        [PXDimensionSelectorAttribute("VENDOR", typeof(Search<VendorR.bAccountID, Where<VendorR.type, Equal<BAccountType.vendorType>,
                                        And<VendorR.status, Equal<BAccount.status.active>>>>),
            typeof(VendorR.acctCD), new Type[] { typeof(VendorR.acctCD), typeof(VendorR.acctName) },DescriptionField = typeof(VendorR.acctName))]    
        [PXUIEnabled(typeof(Where<PMBudgetExt.usrMarkforPO, Equal<False>>))]
        public virtual int? UsrVendorID { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrVendorID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<usrVendorID> { }
        #endregion

        #region UsrMarkforPO

        [PXDBBool()]
        [PXDefault(false)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Mark for PO" )]    
        public virtual bool? UsrMarkforPO { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrMarkforPO : PX.Data.BQL.BqlBool.Field<usrMarkforPO> { }
        #endregion

        #region UsrAcctName
                                                        [PXString(60)]        
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Vendor Name", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible,Enabled =false)]

        public virtual string UsrAcctName { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrAcctName : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrAcctName> { }
        #endregion

        #region UsrPOProcessed
                                                        [PXDBBool()]
 [PXDefault(false)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName="PO Processed")]

        public virtual bool? UsrPOProcessed { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrPOProcessed : PX.Data.BQL.BqlBool.Field<usrPOProcessed> { }
        #endregion
    }
}


 **public class ProjectEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ProjectEntry>
    {      

        public PXAction<PX.Objects.PM.PMProject> Calculate;
        [PXButton]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Mark for PO")]
        public virtual void  calculate ()
        {
            PMProject pro = Base.Project.Current;
            PMCostBudget row = Base.CostBudget.Current;
            PMCostBudget newRow = Base.CostBudget.Current;

            PMBudgetExt newRowE = PXCache<PMBudget>.GetExtension<PMBudgetExt>(newRow);

            string valor = "";
            foreach (CSAnswers item in Base.Answers.Select())
            {
                if (item.AttributeID == "PROJTYPE")
                {
                    valor = item.Value;
                    break;
                }
            }


            if (newRowE.UsrMarkforPO == false && newRowE.UsrVendorID != null && row.RevisedQty > 0 && pro.DefaultBranchID != null && pro.Status == ProjectStatus.Active && valor != null)
            {
                newRowE.UsrMarkforPO = true;        
            }          
        }



        public delegate IEnumerable CopyProjectDelegate(PXAdapter adapter);
        [PXOverride]
        public IEnumerable CopyProject(PXAdapter adapter, CopyProjectDelegate baseMethod)
        {
            foreach (PMCostBudget item in Base.CostBudget.Select())
            {
                PMBudgetExt newRowE = PXCache<PMBudget>.GetExtension<PMBudgetExt>(item);

                if (newRowE != null && newRowE.UsrMarkforPO == true)
                {
                    newRowE.UsrMarkforPO = false;
                }
            }

            return baseMethod(adapter);
        }      

        protected void PMCostBudget_InventoryID_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {

            var row = (PMCostBudget)e.Row;
            PMCostBudget newRow = (PMCostBudget)e.Row;
            if (newRow == null) return;
            PMBudgetExt newRowE = PXCache<PMBudget>.GetExtension<PMBudgetExt>(newRow);
            if (newRowE == null) return;

            foreach (POVendorInventory res in PXSelect<POVendorInventory,
                Where<POVendorInventory.inventoryID,
             In<Required<POVendorInventory.inventoryID>>>>.Select(Base, row.InventoryID))
            {
                if (res != null && res.IsDefault == true)
                {
                    newRowE.UsrVendorID = res.VendorID;
                }
            }
        }

        protected void PMCostBudget_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            PMCostBudget row = (PMCostBudget)e.Row;
            PMCostBudget newRow = (PMCostBudget)e.Row;
            if (newRow == null) return;
            PMBudgetExt newRowE = PXCache<PMBudget>.GetExtension<PMBudgetExt>(newRow);
            if (newRowE == null) return;

            BAccount2 ba = PXSelect<BAccount2, Where<BAccount2.bAccountID,
            In<Required<BAccount2.bAccountID>>>>.Select(Base, newRowE.UsrVendorID);
            if (ba == null) newRowE.UsrAcctName = string.Empty;
            if (ba != null) newRowE.UsrAcctName = ba.AcctName;

            PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<PMBudgetExt.usrMarkforPO>(cache, e.Row, false);

        }

    }**
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It appears that you are using the action Calculate for the button.  I see where you are setting the value on the object newRowE, but you have not actually updated the database with the value.

It is preferable to update the view, but it may be easiest in this case to access the cache directly to save it since it is a DAC extension.  You need to complete 2 steps to update the cache AND save it.  If you do this in other places and already have a Save occurring through other means (like user interaction) then the manual save step would be redundant.  Here are 3 ways you can perform database updates (in case one scenario works better for you in other situations).

```
Base.Caches[typeof(PMBudget)].Update(newRowE);
Base.Save.Press();
```

-or-

```
Base.Caches[typeof(PMBudget)].SetValueExt<PMBudgetExt.UsrMarkforPO>(row, true)
Base.Caches[typeof(PMBudget)].Persist(PXDBOperation.Update);
```

-or-

```
Base.CostBudget.Update(row);
Base.Save.Press();
```

Comment: The second method is the most likely to work in all context because it persist only the PMBudget object. The first one and third one are equivalent and will persist all dataviews.